# the advantage of reading open source code

Tags: open-source

I know there is no clear answer to this question. I still wonder to know whether Reading open source code can improve myself rapidly? how and why?

ps：I keep reading open source code every day for months.

Comment: This is really an opinion-generating question. Best suited for a discussion forum, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, many of the bigger open source projects are collaborations between many people: Thus you do have a chance of finding a project written by good developers, and therefore improve your own coding style. Of course, it all depends if you actually memorise the stuff you read or not - But I guess you wouldn't really read that much code if you didn't.

In my opinion, you can learn the following from **well-written** projects:

- Coding conventions
- Solutions to common problems (Of course, this depends heavily on the "type" of the project)
- How to document code properly - If multiple people work on something, and the project is well-written, it probably also has a good documentation.

Of course, all of this is opinion-based, so you need to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answers (this is highly subjective)

- Because working with someone else's code is more difficult than working with my own code. It forces me to adapt to some else's thinking ("If all I have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail")
- Because open-source code is often not written under a deadline, by people who enjoy what they are working at, and *can* provide high-quality real-world examples
- Because open-source code tends to have less of an agenda to push vendor XYZ's proprietary pet technology
- Because the world might become a slighly better place, if people wouldn't code for the CPU as their main audience, but a human reader :)